# how to find the username using Ipaddress or Hostname?

Tags: c#, windows, directoryservices

I have find the Ipaddress and Hostname using the active directory 
ComputerPrincipal method.but not find the username in this method.i need the username in my domain .how to do this?

here it my code

```
namespace Directory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "xxx.com"))
            {
                using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new ComputerPrincipal(context)))
                {
                    foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
                    {
                        var auth = result as AuthenticablePrincipal;
                        if (auth != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + auth.Name);
                            Console.WriteLine("Last Logon Time: " + auth.LastLogon);
                            if (auth.Name != "Txx-Cxx-Gxx-Pxx")
                            {
                                IPAddress[] ipaddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(auth.Name);
                                foreach (IPAddress ipaddr in ipaddress)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(ipaddr);
                                }

                                Console.WriteLine();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You want to get the Username which they used to log in to the system.? Windows User right.?

Comment: Yeah correct,i want the username ,last logoff time in the system

Comment: Please refer the answer

Comment: thanks a lot.. in this method we get current user only, but i have collection of ip address from my domain so i need to find which user logged in the system using ip address.

Comment: This assumes that only one user can be logged on the computer....

Comment: Yeah yes and how to check the same user login the multiple system at same time?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UserPrincipalName` property of `AuthenticablePrincipal` class.
 for example:

```
   var auth = result as AuthenticablePrincipal;
   var userName = auth.UserPrincipalName;
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal?view=netframework-4.7.2) all properties, methods etc.. that `AuthenticablePrincipal` has.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Windows logged in User

```
string m_strUserName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Please refer other details provided by [WindowsIdentity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity?view=netframework-4.7.2)